# Where is stored the database retrieved by context.getDatabasePath("db1").getAbsolutePath()

Tags: android

I need to delete all the databases stored in the database space of the application. I stored them using this path: context.getDatabasePath("db1").getAbsolutePath()

I have a lot of databases, with random names, so i dont know al the names, i just want to delete all of them.

I tryed with this:

```
String filesDir = ApplicationContextProvider.getContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();  
            File cache = new File(filesDir);
            if (cache.isDirectory()) {
                String[] children = cache.list();
                for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Deleting: "+children[i]);
                     new File(cache, children[i]).delete();
                }
            }
```

But it doesn't works. The databases are still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to know that path. Just use the list of databases you can get to delete them.

```
for (String databaseName : context.databaseList()) {
    context.deleteDatabase(databaseName);
}
```

If you really need it

```
File databasesPath = context.getDatabasePath("ignored").getParentFile();
```

The path you get via `getFilesDir` is a different one.